# overflow works only for bullets, not for the content of li

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem. I have a directive (`aDirective`) which creates an `elementA` (a square with some text), and what I'm trying to do is to add `elementsA` in another `componentB` (by pressing a button). I also want to have a scroll when the number of `elementsA` is too big.

```
.scrollBox{
    height: 430px;
    width: 415px;
    overflow: auto;
}


<ul class="scrollBox">
   <li ng-repeat="i in array" aDirective></li>
</ul>
```

The scroll part doesn't work properly. When I add a specific number of `elementsA`, the scroll bar appears, but it's hiding only the bullets, not the square with text.

Thanks.

Comment: Give a `display: block` for the `.scrollBox`. Let us know the outcome?

Comment: list-style:none? or are you just wanting to show one box at a time? - in which case you will need to set the dimensions of the li to match the parent

Comment: nothing is changed...

Comment: the list is empty at the biginning and by pressing one button you can add an item, This part works very well. The problem is with the scroll who hides only the bullets and lets the squares in their iniatial position no matter what

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to scroll the li's not the ul you should apply the overflow to that.

```css
.scrollBox li {
  height: 3em;
  overflow-Y: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="scrollBox">
  <li ng-repeat="i in array" aDirective>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </li>
  <li ng-repeat="i in array" aDirective>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li ng-repeat="i in array" aDirective>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li ng-repeat="i in array" aDirective>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li ng-repeat="i in array" aDirective>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li ng-repeat="i in array" aDirective>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li ng-repeat="i in array" aDirective>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li ng-repeat="i in array" aDirective>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li ng-repeat="i in array" aDirective>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li ng-repeat="i in array" aDirective>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li ng-repeat="i in array" aDirective>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li ng-repeat="i in array" aDirective>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li ng-repeat="i in array" aDirective>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li ng-repeat="i in array" aDirective>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li ng-repeat="i in array" aDirective>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li ng-repeat="i in array" aDirective>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li ng-repeat="i in array" aDirective>lorem ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Then i'm afraid i don't understand your question?

Comment: imagine that instead of "lorem ipsum" in this list,  you have something else, not pure text, but a square with some fields, data, etc. In this case, the scroll bar works only for the bullets, not for the squares.

Comment: Then you'll need to apply the overflow to the li not the container. I've updated my answer.